# database created? login button does nothing.AndroidStudio,sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Sorry for my English.
I have created a simple application of log and registry with database.
if I register a user I need to log and that the application takes me to another screen.
the problem is not if the logs are created, the login button does absolutely nothing

## MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button registrar;
    Button iniciar;
    BaseDatos bd = new BaseDatos(this, "bd1", null, 1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registro);
        registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent m = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registrar.class);
                startActivity(m);
            }
        });
        iniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iniciar);
        iniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                try {
                    Cursor cursor = bd.check(editText.getText().toString(), editText1.getText().toString());
                    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                        Intent m = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Musica.class);
                        startActivity(m);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    editText.setText("");
                    editText1.setText("");
                    editText.findFocus();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## Registrar.java

```
public class Registrar extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nombre, usuario, password, puesto;
    Button reg;
    BaseDatos bd = new BaseDatos(this, "bd1",null,1);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
        final BaseDatos Bdu = new BaseDatos(this, "bd1", null, 1);

        reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        puesto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.puesto);
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bd.abrir();
                bd.nuevosUsuarios(String.valueOf(nombre.getText()),
                        String.valueOf(usuario.getText()),
                        String.valueOf(password.getText()),
                        String.valueOf(puesto.getText()));
                bd.cerrar();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registro guardado con exito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent m = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(m);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## BaseDatos.java

```
public class BaseDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public BaseDatos(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

        @Override
        public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){
            String query = ("create table trabajadores(_ID integer primary key autoincrement, Nombre text, Usuario text, Password text,Puesto text)");

        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion){
            db.execSQL("insert into trabajadores values(01,'admin','admin')");
        }
        public void abrir ()

        {
            this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        public void cerrar ()
        {
        this.close();
        }
    public void nuevosUsuarios (String nom, String usr, String pass, String pues){
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("Nombre", nom);
            valores.put("Usuario", usr);
            valores.put("Password", pass);
            valores.put("Puesto", pues);
            this.getWritableDatabase().insert("trabajadores", null, valores);
        }
    public Cursor check( String usr, String pass) throws SQLException{
        Cursor rcursor=null;
        rcursor=this.getReadableDatabase().query("trabajadores", new String[]{"_ID,","Nombre","Usuario","Password","Puesto"},
        "Usuario like '"+usr+"'"+" and Password like'"+pass+"'",null,null,null,null);
        return rcursor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. I was not able to understand what is your `login` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't creating the table.

In the BaseDatos.java in the onCreate method add the line :-

```
db.execSQL(query);
```

So the method should be :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){
    String query = ("create table trabajadores(_ID integer primary key autoincrement, Nombre text, Usuario text, Password text,Puesto text)");
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

There is also an issue the the **check** method that will result in a SQlite syntax error due to an extra **`,`**.

Instead of

```
rcursor=this.getReadableDatabase().query("trabajadores", new String[]{"_ID,","Nombre","Usuario","Password","Puesto"},
            "Usuario like '"+usr+"'"+" and Password like'"+pass+"'",null,null,null,null);
```

it should be

```
rcursor=this.getReadableDatabase().query("trabajadores", new String[]{"_ID","Nombre","Usuario","Password","Puesto"},
            "Usuario like '"+usr+"'"+" and Password like'"+pass+"'",null,null,null,null);
```

(comma removed after **_ID**).

**Note before running after making the change, delete the App's data or uninstall the App.**

## Demo

### When started :-

[image]

- Note all displays have the Activity's name (as highlighted).
- The red arrow indicates the button that was clicked
- At this stage clicking the INICIAR button just issues a toast.

### Clicking the Registrar button :-

[image]

- User number(1), username (Fred), password (password) and puesto (blah) are entered and the Reg buttons is clicked.

### Returns to the MainActivity

[image]

- Fred and password are entered into the Username and password and the INICIAR button is clicked.

### The Musica Acivity

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help, the log button is still not working, I have reviewed everything from top to bottom and I still do not understand why it is dead

Comment: @Rubennexus With the changes made as above and deleting the App's data your code worked with no issues. However, if you are trying to use the admin user, that never gets added (the onUpgrade method only runs when the database version number is increased).

Comment: @Rubennexus  added demonstration showing that it works when the changes are made as per the answer.

Comment: @Rubennexus, that's good. If you believe that this answered your question or helped you to find the answer then please tick the answer.